# Getting columns from join columns with EF query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How do you get columns from the various join tables with Entity framework and linq?

My sql statement looks like:

```
SELECT
    j1.Username, j2.points, j3.address1
FROM
    users j1
    INNER JOIN points j2 on j1.userId = j2.UserId
    INNER JOIN addresses j3 on j3.userId = j1.UserId
```

So I'm confused how to convert this into a EF/linq query that returns the columns from the joined tables/entities.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should post what you've tried before asking the question ...

It should look like that:

```
var results = from j1 in context.users
              join j2 in context.points on j1.UserId equals j2.UserId
              join j3 in context.addresses on j1.UserId equals j3.UserId
              select new { j1.Username, j2.points, j3.address1 }
```

It will give you a collection of anonymous objects with your 3 columns values.

Comment: ah ok, thanks.  Now if I add a group by clause like `group j1 by j1.CountryCode into g1` that causes a problem as it seems the output is projected into the variable g1 now??

Comment: yes, after grouping like that you will get `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, anonymous_type>>`